# how to use jaxb2 maven plugin with inline XSD?

Tags: java, maven-plugin, spring-ws, jaxb2

I am trying to generate marshalling and unmarshalling objects using maven jaxb2 plugin.
But I dont have the .xsd file for the .wsdl.
the schema definition is inline.
Please let me know how to proceed ?

Comment: I tagged the question with `spring-ws` for you; that you are working in that environment is an important fact that you should have mentioned to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `wsdl` parameter in the plugin config: [jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html)

Comment: I am using the maven-jaxb2-plugin from sun. But can we just extract the xsd from the wsdl and generate? I tried it and working fine. But need to know if its a good way to do ?

Comment: Yes, your approach is also fine.

Comment: Works like a charm. One just needs to include <wsdl>true</wsdl> into the config - compare also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15903250/21499 .

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Maven plugin to work with WSDL files:

http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/