# Generate classes with jaxb2-maven-plugin from WSDL

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am having trouble configuring the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` to generate Java classes from a WSDL and multiple XSD files that all exist in the same standard directory `src/main/xsd`.

[how to use jaxb2 maven plugin with inline XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315651/how-to-use-jaxb2-maven-plugin-with-inline-xsd/) is related only in that the answers correctly suggest using the `wsdl` parameter in the plugin config but that question is really concerned with inline XSDs and my XSDs are external.

The plugin goal parameters are listed [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html).

My plugin configuration is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <packageName>com.x.y.model</packageName>
        <wsdl>true</wsdl>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am testing this with `mvn -X clean jaxb2:xjc` but the plugin is ignoring the `.wsdl` as seen in the debug output

```
[DEBUG] accept false for file c:\projects\foo\src\main\xsd\service.wsdl
[DEBUG] accept true for file c:\projects\foo\src\main\xsd\datatypes.xsd
[DEBUG] accept true for file c:\projects\foo\src\main\xsd\more-datatypes.xsd
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By examining the Maven debug output of the arguments being passed to the JAXB XJC (and a bit of trial and error) I found that I needed to supply 2 more configuration parameters to the plugin.

This stops the plugin scanning for XSD files and just uses the `.wsdl` as the source. The XSD files are included in the WSDL as`<xsd:include schemaLocation="datatypes.xsd" />` directives, for example, which are resolved locally resulting in all types from the WSDL and XSD being generated as Java classes.

The configuration section that worked for me is:

```
<configuration>
    <packageName>com.x.y.model</packageName>
    <wsdl>true</wsdl>
    <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
    <schemaFiles>service.wsdl</schemaFiles>
</configuration>
```

Without the `<xmlschema>false</xmlschema>` Maven errors with:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.5:xjc (default-cli) on project foo: Could not process schema:
>     /c:/projects/foo/src/main/xsd/service.wsdl

Comment: omg, thank you this works when I don't specify a directory and use the default xsd directory

Answer (score 11):

I had this question for jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.5.0. Here is my solution:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
        <sources>
            <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</source>
        </sources>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        <packageName>com.project.generated</packageName>
        <noPackageLevelAnnotations>true</noPackageLevelAnnotations>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: It's a wrong configuration, configuration tag must be inside execution tag.

Answer (score 8):

If you are generating wsdl and xsd as well try to put in a different execution configuration: It may not have the same `schemaDirectory` or the plugin will not run successfully the second execution, cause it caches executions based on this variable. I advice to do it such as

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sri-facturas</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal> 
                    </goals> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/sri</outputDirectory>
                        <packageName>${commonsource.packageName}</packageName> 
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaFiles>factura_v1.1.0.xsd</schemaFiles>
                    </configuration> 
                </execution> 
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sri-autorizacion-comprobantes</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal> 
                    </goals> 
                    <configuration> 
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/sri/autorizacion</outputDirectory>
                        <packageName>${commonsource.packageName}.autorizacion</packageName>
                        <wsdl>true</wsdl>
                        <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaFiles>AutorizacionComprobantes.wsdl</schemaFiles>
                    </configuration> 
                </execution> 
            </executions> 
        </plugin>
```

I created a `xsd` and a `wsdl` folder to separate configurations.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the follows code in the configuration:

```
              <configuration>
                    <!-- Package to store the generated file -->
                    <packageName>com.example.demo.wsdl</packageName>
                    <!-- Treat the input as WSDL -->
                    <wsdl>true</wsdl>
                    <!-- Input is not XML schema -->
                    <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
                    <!-- The WSDL file that you saved earlier -->
                    <schemaFiles>horarios.wsdl</schemaFiles>
                    <!-- The location of the WSDL file -->
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <!-- The output directory to store the generated Java files -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- Don't clear output directory on each run -->
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have tried `jaxb2-maven-plugin` which generate the java file

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/webapp/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
                    <wsdl>true</wsdl>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

To run this i have used the command

```
mvn jaxb2:xjc
```

Try this it will generate the jaxb classes into your src folder. Hope you are looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

For version 2.5 the configuration would be the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <packageName>com.packagename</packageName>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</source>
                </sources>
                <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                <noPackageLevelAnnotations>true</noPackageLevelAnnotations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. plugin com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-maven-plugin:4.0.2 goal wsimport when generating soap client (jakarta namespace)
2. very important dependency com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:4.0.2 type pom

Comment: <plugin>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>${jaxws.maven.plugin.version}</version>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>soap-client</id>
   <goals>
    <goal>wsimport</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <wsdlUrls>
     <wsdlUrl>${wsdl.url}</wsdlUrl>
    </wsdlUrls>
    <packageName>xx.xx.client</packageName>
    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceDestDir>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>