# Generate WSDL with XSD schema from JAX-WS

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have a JAX-WS annotated Webservice, and when I deploy it into a WildFly 8.1.0 Final I have something like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="http://www.viactt.pt" targetNamespace="http://www.viactt.pt" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.viactt.pt"/>
    <xs:element name="wsAccountArray" type="ns1:wsAccountArray"/>
  </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

when what I want is something like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.viactt.pt" schemaLocation="ViaCTTIntegrationService_schema1.xsd"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

So, basically, I want the WildFly/JAX-WS to put some types in a separate XSD schema file instead of just showing them in the WSDL file.

Can I do this via some annotation or via some configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Us XJC plugin of maven(maven-jaxb2-plugin) to re-generate the JAXB object from wsdl . [Click Here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/xjc-mojo.html) for the Tutorial.
You can also [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903249/generate-classes-with-jaxb2-maven-plugin-from-wsdl) .
One more blog is having complete tutorial of it. [Click Here](http://www.albinsblog.com/2014/06/generating-jaxb-artifacts-from-xsdwsdl.html#.VKarxiuUdrM)  to see.