# Maven not generating java class source files from wsdl file

Tags: java, wsdl, maven-3

I have configured the pom file as below,

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <packageName>com.test</packageName>
                <wsdl>true</wsdl>
                <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaFiles>mex.wsdl</schemaFiles>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I am building using maven command its reading the `wsdl` file and build is success.

```
[INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (xjc) ---
[INFO] Generating source...
[INFO] parsing a schema...
[INFO] compiling a schema...
```

But java source files are not getting generated, Not getting what is wrong I have done here.

Comment: If you are running the maven goal in eclipse, please refresh the project folder;)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903249/generate-classes-with-jaxb2-maven-plugin-from-wsdl) ?  Have searched through SO?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Yes I have gone through it, no luck.

Comment: Follow the conventions and don't change the outputDirectory. You should leave the generating into target folder where they belong. Furthermore why are you using such an old version of the plugin? http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/