# jaxb2-maven-plugin not generating sources from wsdl

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have the following configuration for jaxb2-maven-plugin version 2.4

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
        <sources>
            <source>src/main/resources/wsdl/osg_data_sync_service_1_0.wsdl</source>
            <source>src/main/resources/wsdl/parlayx_sms_notification_service_2_2.wsdl</source>
        </sources>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when i run `mvn jaxb2:xjc`, no classes are generated.

What could I be overlooking?

I have pasted one of the wsdl [here](https://pastebin.com/ZSFkF9k8)

**EDIT**

As it was mentioned that this might be a possible duplicate, I downgraded the plugin to version `1.6` and changed configuration to the following and still no classes generated.

```
<configuration>
    <wsdl>true</wsdl>
    <xmlschema>false</xmlschema
    <schemaFiles>osg_data_sync_interface_1_0.wsdl,parlayx_sms_notification_interface_2_2.wsdl</schemaFiles>
    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/generated</outputDirectory> 
</configuration>
```

Full pom [here](https://pastebin.com/NquQwyLU) as site was complaining too much code

It finally works with version `1.6` after cleaning. Why does version `2.4` not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate classes with jaxb2-maven-plugin from WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903249/generate-classes-with-jaxb2-maven-plugin-from-wsdl)

Comment: What is your maven version? `mvn -v`

Comment: @MarinosAn `Maven 3.6.0`

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting any errors on the console? e.g. regarding wsdl parsing. If not I would suggest providing the full `pom.xml`

Comment: @MarinosAn not getting any errors

Comment: Does the same happen with `mvn generate-sources`? As said providing full `pom.xml` might help.

Comment: @MarinosAn it finally works with version `1.6` using the phase after cleaning. I wonder why version `2.4` doesn't work?

Comment: FYI: I have tested with 2.4 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got version `2.4` to work. I don't know exactly what the issue was but I was able to generate the classes by running `mvn generate-sources` instead of `mvn jaxb2:xjc` as suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260020/jaxb2-maven-plugin-not-generating-sources-from-wsdl?noredirect=1#comment97253568_55260020). I also had to run `mvn clean` first

Comment: This indeed made it work for me.. Have to "generate-sources" not "jaxb:xjc".. Thank you for your answer!